# Can I rethrow a rejected await function, and catch it immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, async-await, jestjs

I'd like to catch all my exceptions in one place, but I [can't do that currently](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/throw-async/#how-to-throw-errors-from-async-functions-in-javascript-catch-me-if-you-can):

> There is an important thing to note if you like more try/catch. The following code won't catch the error:
> [...]
> Remember: a rejected Promise will propagate up in the stack unless you catch it. To catch the error properly in try/catch you would refactor like so:
>
> ```
> whatever().catch(err => console.error(err));
> ```

But here is my code as I would like to have it:

```js
async function getMtgJsonVersion() {
  try {
    const response = await axios(metaUrl).catch((err) => { throw err; });
    const { data: { meta: { version } } } = response;
    return version;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Could not fetch MTG JSON metadata: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

and my test:

```
// console.error is mocked higher up in the test file
it.only('handles errors in fetching', async () => {
  expect.assertions(2);
  axios.mockReset(); // I use mockImplementationOnce elsewhere
  axios.mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('bang'));
  expect(() => getMtgJsonVersion()).rejects.toThrow('bang');
  expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.stringContaining('bang'));
});
```

But when I run it, I get that the last expect is not fulfilled?

> ```
> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)  
>    Expected: StringContaining "bang"  
>    Number of calls: 0
> ```

I was hoping to catch all my throws in one place, but it looks like it's not as simple as I thought.

Is this possible, and how?

Comment: Are you mocking / spying on `console.error`? If not then I don't think jest will be able to check calls made to it

Comment: @tom I am, much further up in the file. I'll clarify

Comment: `await expect(() => getMtgJsonVersion()).rejects.toThrow('bang');`

Comment: @hoangdv can you explain that or post an answer with an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `expect(fn).rejects.*` is an asynchronous action, then it will take "a little time" to finish.

In your code, `expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.stringContaining('bang'))` will run before `expect(() => getMtgJsonVersion()).rejects.toThrow('bang');` line. At that time, the `console.log` is not be called yet.

To make it work as your expectation, you have to wait until  `getMtgJsonVersion` finishes,  then assert on the log function. `rejects.toThrow('bang')` return a promise, then just wait for it with `await` keyword:

```
await expect(() => getMtgJsonVersion()).rejects.toThrow('bang');
expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.stringContaining('bang'));
```

My note: Avoid using `try/catch` in "child" unit, just use it in the "final parent" function, if you just want to log when the http request is failed:

```
async function getMtgJsonVersion() {
  const { data } = await axios(metaUrl).catch((error) => {
    console.error(`Could not fetch MTG JSON metadata: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  });
  return data.meta.version.
}
```

Comment: This is great. I think I put the await in the wrong place at some point (which failed), and brain-farted myself into thinking the `.rejects.` unwrapping meant I didn't need it.